# $(M\otimes_A N)_B \cong M_B\otimes_B N_B$?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A \rightarrow B$ be a homomorphism of commutative rings.
Let $M, N$ be $A$-modules.
We denote $M\otimes_A B$ by $M_B$.
We regard $M_B$ as a $B$-module.
Then $(M\otimes_A N)_B \cong M_B\otimes_B N_B$?

Comment: This has been asked when the map is a localization [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41750/help-understand-canonical-isomorphism-in-localization-tensor-products) and the answer is the same.

Comment: @YACP I didn't say I wouldn't accept it. It's usually not a good idea to accept an answer too soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an isomorphism of $A$-modules

$$M_B \otimes_B N_B \cong (M \otimes_A B) \otimes_B (B \otimes_A N) \cong M \otimes_A (B \otimes_B B) \otimes_A N \cong M \otimes_A B \otimes_A N \cong (M \otimes_A N)_B.$$

By its explicit description on elements (or some diagram) it is easily seen to be $B$-linear.

A more detailed proof can be found in many treatments of algebra, for example N. Bourbaki, Elements of Mathematics, Algebra I, Chapter II, §5, Prop 3.